# merge json.parse with the src manual route

Tags: json, laravel

I want to ask, how about when I want to combine

```
obj.user.photo_ktp
obtained from 
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

with

```
src ="{{(\Auth::user()->photo_ktp=='user_default.png'||\Auth::user()->photo_ktp==' ') ? asset('/public/assets/img/card.png'):\Auth::user()->photo_ktp}} "
```

where I want to replace `Auth::user()->photo_ktp` with `obj.user.photo_ktp`

Answer (score 0):

try ${obj}

```
src ="{{(\Auth::user()->photo_ktp=='user_default.png'||\Auth::user()->photo_ktp==${obj}) ? asset('/public/assets/img/card.png'):\Auth::user()->photo_ktp}} "
```